# How to make a Select from DB where DB is from a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a .NET project with 3 databases (`Common`, `Akten_DE`, `Akten_IT`). All 3 databases are on same SQL Server. In databases `Akten_DE` and `Akten_IT` I have a table `Akt` where I store acts from DE or IT. But in database `Common` I have the table `AktComm` where I store all acts from both database. In table `AktComm` in `Common` I also have a column `DB` where I store acts database name.

Table `Akt` in `Akten_DE`:

```
|ID        | ...
|AKT140122 | ... 
|AKT140131 | ...
```

Table `Akt` in `Akten_IT`:

```
|ID        | ...
|AKT140127 | ... 
|AKT140162 | ...
```

Table `AktComm` in `Common`:

```
|ID        |DB       |
----------------------
|AKT140122 |Akten_DE |
|AKT140127 |Akten_IT |
|AKT140131 |Akten_DE |
|AKT140162 |Akten_IT |
----------------------
```

The question is how can I write a select in the `Common` database but take the data from `Akten_IT` or from `Akten_DE` depending on the value of `Common.dbo.AktComm.DB`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT akt.* 
FROM AktComm comAkt 
INNER JOIN "comAkt.DB".dbo.Akt akt ON comAkt.ID = akt.ID
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the table Akt has the same schema in each database.

The basic query to do this is a simple join across database and union together the results:

```
SELECT co.ID, de.*
FROM AktComm co
JOIN AKTEN_DE.dbo.Akt de   
  ON co.ID = de.ID collate database_default
 AND co.DB = 'Akten_DE'
UNION ALL
SELECT co.ID, it.*
FROM AktComm co
JOIN AKTEN_DE.dbo.Akt it
  ON co.ID = it.ID collate database_default
 AND co.DB = 'Akten_IT'
```

Of course, this is not very flexible as when you add new databases you need to refactor your query. The dynamic sql below will query the databases if new ones are added. Do note that I don't filter on `DB` because this would introduce a SQL injection leak and in the grand scheme of things the performance difference will be marginal if the AktComm table is not partitioned on the DB field.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

;WITH dbs as (select distinct DB from AktComm where db_id(DB) is not null)
select @sql = isnull(@sql + N' UNION ALL', N'') + N'
  SELECT co.ID, ' + QUOTENAME(DB) + N'.*
    FROM AktComm co
    JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(DB) + N'.dbo.Akt de   
      ON co.ID = de.ID collate database_default'
  from dbs
 print (@sql)
 exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Second part of this answer is the best for me because in future I will have more that one database. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that easily - you'd have to do a comparison against the `Common.AktComm.DB` column and then execute on or the other `SELECT` statement:

```
DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @DB = AktComm.DB 
FROM Common
WHERE ID = akt.ID

IF (@DB = 'Akten_DE') THEN
   SELECT akt.* 
   FROM AktComm comAkt 
   INNER JOIN Akten_DE akt ON comAkt.ID = akt.ID
END

IF (@DB = 'Akten_IT') THEN
   SELECT akt.* 
   FROM AktComm comAkt 
   INNER JOIN Akten_IT akt ON comAkt.ID = akt.ID
END
```

You cannot "parametrize" database, table or column names with parameter values or values from a database column.

Answer (score 1):

This will work (though it may be too slow for your needs, depending on the amount of data etc.) for your example, though it is probably untenable if your real world problem has more than two or three databases.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(AKTde.ID, aktIT.ID) AS ID
FROM 
    AktComm comAkt 
    LEFT JOIN AKTEN_DE.dbo.Akt aktDE 
        ON comAkt.ID = aktDE.ID
        AND comAkt.DB = 'Akten_DE'
    LEFT JOIN AKTEN_IT.dbo.Akt aktIT 
        ON comAkt.ID = aktIT.ID
        AND comAkt.DB = 'Akten_IT'
```